# Paypal payment after condition is met

Tags: paypal

I would like to know if paypal offers something to solve the following problem:

- User pays for virtual currency for the first time (user interaction)
- When user is about to consume all of the virtual currency, take money again from the user paypal account (no user interaction)

I've been looking through Paypal documentation and found recurring payments, but they are done every X time, not when a condition is met.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation I found that several payment providers offer a service called **Vault** where you can store credit card information and get an **identifier** back to use for future transactions.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-vault-overview/
https://stripe.com/docs/tutorials/charges#saving-credit-card-details-for-later